# Find $f(n)$ , $f(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\binom{n+1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2^{n+4}}\binom{n+3}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+6}}\binom{n+5}{6}+ \cdots$

Tags: combinatorics

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Find $f(n)$? (n $\in \mathbb{N}$ )

$$f(n)=\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+2}}\binom{n+1}{2}+ \frac{1}{2^{n+4}}\binom{n+3}{4}+\frac{1}{2^{n+6}}\binom{n+5}{6}+ \cdots$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$(1+x)^{-n}=1+(-n)x+\dfrac{(-n)(-n-1)}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)}{3!}x^3+...$
$(1-x)^{-n}=1-(-n)x+\dfrac{(-n)(-n-1)}{2!}x^2-\dfrac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)}{3!}x^3+...$

By adding

$\dfrac{1}{2}((1+x)^{-n}+(1-x)^{-n})=1+\dfrac{(-n)(-n-1)}{2!}x^2+\dfrac{(-n)(-n-1)(-n-2)(-n-3)}{4!}x^4+...$

$1+\binom{n+1}{2}x^2+\binom{n+3}{4}x^4+...=\dfrac{1}{2}((1+x)^{-n}+(1-x)^{-n})$

substituting $x=\dfrac{1}{2}$,
$1+\binom{n+1}{2}\dfrac{1}{2^2}+\binom{n+3}{4}\dfrac{1}{2^4}+...=\dfrac{1}{2}((\dfrac{3}{2})^{-n}+(\dfrac{1}{2})^{-n})$

multiplying through $\dfrac{1}{2^n}$,

$f(n)=\dfrac{1}{2}({3^{-n}+1})$

Comment: Thank You for your answer!!